# Using onclick() inside another function

Tags: javascript

```
function layoutMod() {
    standardId = document.getElementById("standard");
    fancyId = document.getElementById("fancy");
    standardId.onclick = function() {
        standard();
    };

    fancyId.onclick = function() {
        fancy();
    };
};
```

How can I use the onclick events defined above in a function??? Is it a good practice to load the function at page load?? I need to define in a function the onclick event beacuse I don't want to use global variables.

Comment: First of all, always use the `var` keyword. The way you have it now all your variables are not limited to just this function and are probably global! [Use strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) to help avoid common issues like these. Second, your `standardId` and `fancyId` variables seem to be poorly named. `getElementById` returns a DOM element, not an id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[It can get messing when you nest functions inside of each other.](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/stop-nesting-functions-but-not-all-of-them--net-22315) In this case, I would suggest removing the outer function so that your code looks like this:

```
document.getElementById("standard").onclick = function() {
 standard();
};
document.getElementById("fancy").onclick = function() {
 fancy();
};
```

The code does not need to be in a function, it will automatically be run on page load. Since you don't want global variables, just don't use variables at all.

Comment: this would make him use global variables. I think what he did is fine and won't do harm performance wise.

Comment: if you have jquery you can also do, $("#standard").click(function(){})

Answer (score 3):

What you've written should work. However, you should note that by not using the `var` keyword, you're still creating global variables inside of your function. I would suggest...

```
function onloadHandler() {
    document.getElementById("standard").onclick = function() {
        // Do something
    };

    document.getElementById("fancy").onclick = function() {
        // Do something else
    };
};
```

Comment: How onloadhandler() will be called, only if I call it on onload() ?? that means this function will be called twice, once on onload and once when I click one of two links (document.getElementById("standard") or document.getElementById("fancy"), is that right?

Comment: inside function will not trigger unless you click..., outside function shouldn't trigger twice, try adding a console.log to it to check.

Comment: Only if I call it once.. then will trigger

Comment: I believe the trigger inside won't trigger if outside closure function isn't trigger. so yes you would need to trigger it. You can also self trigger it if you don't want it to be triggered by onload handler.

Comment: Sorry, you'll need to call the outside function. I thought that was obvious. You can either call it on body onload... `<body onload="onloadHandler()">` or you could call it in a `<script>` tag at the bottom of your page.

Comment: Ok, I think in the end this is what I'm going to do. Thank you very much